# How can I dismiss dialog in fragment on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

My fragment is just simple like this:

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment  implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_1, container, false);

        bt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
            return v;
        }


        private void buildAlertDialog() {
            private void buildAlertDialog() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width) / 7, (2 * height) / 5);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            buildAlertDialog();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
        }
```

And my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

As you can see I did not set anything to save state but when I rotate the device, the dialog keep showing up. What I want is to dismiss it. What should I do? Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally it should disappear,maybe it's because you show your dialog in `onCreateView()`  when device rotate `onCreateView()` call and your dialog show again.
you can show your dialog by click or anything or use a flag to keep if dialog shown before.

**UPDATE:**
change dialog `width` and `height` in this

```
        WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        int screenWidth = (int)(display.getWidth() * 6)/7;
        int screenHeight = (int)(display.getHeight() * 2)/7;
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = screenHeight;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: oh sorry, this is just demo code so I did not notice that. In real project, I make the dialog appear when I click a button, not in onCreateView()

Comment: I knew what cause the problem. The problem appear when I add DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
**and** 
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout((6 * width) / 7, (2 * height) / 5); to the button click function. Please teach me how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

when you rotate your device the activty is re-created, so the dialog is shown again, all you need to do is to add prevent that by adding this line of code in your manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

see : [Android Dialog reopen after rotate device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816018/android-dialog-reopen-after-rotate-device)

Comment: I edited my question. pls take a look at buildDialog() method ;)